# Azure Functions Elastic Premium Plan and Queue Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

We have a solution where we use an Azure Storage Queue to process messages that take approx 6 minutes.

I've read that the maximum `batchSize` of Queue messages concurrently processed are `32` per VM.

> If the function app scales out to multiple VMs, each VM could run one instance of each queue-triggered function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json

How does that translate to `Azure Functions Premium plan`?
Lets say we want to be able to process `64` messages at once using Azure Functions Premium plan with `Always ready instances`. If we have `2` ready instances, can they process  2 * 32 concurrent messages? Or do they underwater really need to be on seperate VM's and 2 instances will not do anything different?

> In the Premium plan, you can have your app always ready on a specified number of instances. The maximum number of always ready instances is 20. When events begin to trigger the app, they are first routed to the always ready instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#always-ready-instances

Comment: In Azure Functions premium plan, if you have pre-warmed instance, then that is given a dedicated VM instance. So, if you had 2 VM instances running your function app, then they can process 2*(`batchSize` + `newBatchThreshold`) concurrent Queue messages!

Comment: So you are saying that every new instance of a function is to be thought of as a new VM instance? Somehow that confuses me a bit. A VM sounds like a lot more than a mere extra instance of an application. I did test it out though just now and the processing of messages did scale.

Comment: Every new instance of the function is _not_. The whole function app is hosted in the vm, and that is what is scaled. Each vm may be running hundreds of invocations of azure function(s). For queue triggered functions concurrent invocations is capped.

Comment: Yes sorry that is actually what I meant. My bad.  The function app is what I referred to as "a mere extra instance of an application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In Azure Functions premium plan, if you have pre-warmed instance, then that is given a *dedicated* VM instance. So, if you had 2 VM instances running your function app, then they can process 2*(`batchSize` + `newBatchThreshold`) concurrent Queue messages!
The Azure platform scales the function app onto new VM as the existing instances gets more busy.